# ExpressionEngine - related_categories_mode not working

Tags: expressionengine

Have a fairly basic template that outputs the main article and then should output three others from the same channel, however when using the following code nothing is output in the "Other partners" area, not even "No posts" so I'm really not sure what's going wrong. There's 5+ articles in the system so there's definitely results to pull out, any ideas?

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="partner" limit="1" url_title="{segment_3}"}

              <article>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                {profile_logo:banner wrap="image"}
                {profile_body}
              </article>

{/exp:channel:entries}    

<h2>Other Partners</h2>
{exp:channel:entries channel="partner" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
   {if no_results}
     No posts
    {/if}
              <article>
                <a href="{url_title_path='community/partners'}">
                  {profile_logo:thumbnail wrap="image"}
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                  <p>{profile_body}</p>
                </a>
              </article>
              {/if}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Nick, are you aware of the EE Beta SE (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)... Do you need an invite so you can post EE questions there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a random `{/if}`, not sure if that's causing the issues with the results. You could always pass the current category to a embed and run it like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="partner" limit="1" url_title="{segment_3}"}

  <article>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {profile_logo:banner wrap="image"}
    {profile_body}
  </article>

  {embed="template_group/_related_partners" category="{categories backspace="1"}{category_id}|{/categories}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

**Embed template:**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="partner" category="{embed:category}" dynamic="no" url_title="not {segment_3}"}
   {if no_results}
   No posts
   {/if}
   <article>
    <a href="{url_title_path='community/partners'}">
      {profile_logo:thumbnail wrap="image"}
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{profile_body}</p>
    </a>
   </article>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Good catch. Check that spurious `{/if}` tag!

Answer (score 1):

Probably all you need to do here is add `dynamic="no"` parameter to your second channel entries loop where you are using `related_categories_mode`. You need to do this because you are on a single entry page and EE will try to use the `url_title` present in `segment_3` to load channel data for that entry specifically.

So you should try:

```
<h2>Other Partners</h2>
{exp:channel:entries channel="partner" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes" dynamic="no"}
    [...]
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Official documentation for the `dynamic=` parameter is [here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic).

Also be sure the entry you are loading in the browser is categorized in such a way that there are indeed other entries in that channel that are similarly categorized. Without some other entries that share the same category(ies) no entries will be loaded by the channel loop where you are using `related_categories_mode`.

Also, as @Seibird mentioned, it does look like you have an extra closing `if` tag after the closing `article` tag in your code example. That is likely to be interfering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but just tried this and it still doesn't want to work. thought I must have written some markup incorrectly but seems not… really confused by this one!

Comment: @Nick The other thing to check then is to be sure the entry you are loading in the browser is categorized in such a way that there are other entries in that channel that are similarly categorized. Without some other entries that have the same category no entries will  be loaded by the `related_categories_mode` channel loop. Have you confirmed that?

Comment: Yes, when I remove "related_categories_mode="yes"" from the query it outputs all 5 of the articles including the one you're on, when I add it in it outputs nothing, not even the "No Posts" message, has me totally confused…! tempted to just do that and add url_title="not {segment_3}" instead but it's not as clean…

Comment: And you have checked that this channel has a category group, with categories, assigned to it? And that the entry you are loading has been categorized similarly to at least a few other entries? You'll have to manually apply the categories. Obvious, I know, but would explain the behavior you are seeing.